# spring xml based config autowire issue

Tags: java, spring

I am running a spring application with xml configuration. I have defined two beans in the application-configuration.xml followed as

```
   <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="myDataSource"
       class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
   </bean>
```

and I am trying to get the bean simply as

```
public class SQLDbService {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void someMethod()
    {
        jdbcTemplate.execute();
    }
}
```

but the jdbcTemplate field is always null. 
The application starts from another class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-configuration.xml");
}
```

I tried adding

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

to application configuration. 
I would like to know if an annotation-based autowiring is possible at this point, if so, what I am missing?

Comment: is SQLDbService managed by spring?

Comment: is `SQLDbService` also a bean or standalone class? Do you have bean definition fot this class in your xml?

Comment: hello it is a standalone class and is not defined in the xml.

Comment: Then how can spring @Autowire it. Write a bean declaration for that in your xml

Comment: do I have to change anything in the code I provided besides the xml ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   <bean id="sQLDbService" class="path.to.your.package.SQLDbService">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
   </bean>
```